# import between front-end/backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having the below error as I am trying to import the `getUser` function in my backend.

The actual function is in the frontend (`../utils/auth`).
How can I import between front-end/backend? Or is there a different issue?

```
C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\Week-9\finalproject\api\routes\index.js:9
import { getUser } from '../utils/auth'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)      
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\charl\Desktop\IRONHACK\Week-9\finalproject\api\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `getUser`. Your error is SyntaxError.
Try use:

```
const { getUser } = require('../utils/auth');
```

Answer (score -1):

Because Frontend and backend are different process, the frontend code is download and executed on client browsers, so you must have `getUser` function in frontend source code. I never recommend sharing code between front-end/backend.

Comment: so how can I solve this then? how can I get access to the getUser?

Comment: This is not something related to different process.

Comment: I mean, if you want to run code in frontend, you must put your code in frontend directory